# Facebook Graph API (Graph API Explorer vs own app)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to integrate Facebook API into my iPhone app.

I have found the problem when I use own app and try to fetch statuses of an another user it returns everytime:

```
   {
      "data": [
       ]
   }
```

but when use Graph Api Explorer for this purposes it returns a data with all public statuses of user.

The all statuses are public, everyone can read it. May be use FQL but Facebook recommends use Graph API?

What is a problem there?

Another question if previous will have no solution: Can I read the public status of any user? May be I can subscribe to an user and see his public comments with other Graph API request.

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to `/me/permissions` with both apps and check you have the same [Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) granted to each application - you're likely missing the `read_stream` permission on the other app

Comment: Hello lgy. Thank you for response. Unfortunately it doesn't help me. I have read_stream permissions in my iPhone app and in Graph API Explorer too. Now I can read the statuses of my friends (so permission was added). But there is no success with public statuses of person who isn't my friend.

Comment: Did you test your app with another person? For example, the ID of person is 100000881708201. I can't read his statuses with own app in Graph Api Explorer tools but I easily do it with Graph Api Explorer Facebook app there.

Comment: There are some screens : permissions - [permissions](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5481335/Screen%20Shot%202012-06-15%20at%2010.53.15%20AM.png) ; result with own app - [own app](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5481335/Screen%20Shot%202012-06-15%20at%2010.53.25%20AM.png) ; result with Graph API Explorer app - [Graph API Explorer app](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5481335/Screen%20Shot%202012-06-15%20at%2010.53.53%20AM.png) ; Thank you.